# How to call partially un-nest transformers?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

**Given a nesting of transformers `:: T2 of T1 of M0`, how can I utilize `:: T2 of M0`, `:: M2` ?**

Here's an example: I am writing some function which requires reading, logging, and state. The definition:

```
gameRoutine :: WriterT [String] (ReaderT Env (State Viable)) NUM
```

If I want to call some
 `stateFunction :: State Viable NUM`

Or even `stateWithReaderFunction :: ReaderT Env (State Viable) NUM`,

I can use `lift`:

```
gameRoutine = do
    x <- lift . lift $ stateFunction
    y <- lift $ stateWithReaderFunction
```

But how do I call `writerFunction :: Writer [String] a` ?

How do I call `writerStateFunction :: WriterT [String] (State Viable) NUM` (the difference between `gameRoutine` definition is `ReaderT` layer missing)?

Clearly I don't want to lift their definitions to one of `gameRoutine`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, basically the idea of `mtl` is that you *don't* need to do that. Instead of defining `writerStateFunction` with that specific signature, you define it with a generic signature

```
writerStateFunction' :: (MonadWriter [String] m, MonadState Viable m)
          => m NUM
```

Then it doesn't matter that the environment where you try to use this has an extra `Reader` layer: this doesn't prevent the monad from having both `MonadWriter` and `MonadState` functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that blew my mind. But still, how do use `writerStateFunction'`? Do I need to change `gameRoutine` definition? I don't get what type matches that constraints `(MonadWriter [String] m, MonadState Viable m)`. How is that possible? In my understanding, a transformer wraps a monad and is a monad, but how come it actually inherits inner monad's 'traits'? Definitely a lot to learn yet.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin Both the types `WriterT [String] (StateT m Viable) NUM` and `StateT Viable (WriterT m [String]) NUM` for any `Monad m` (and also either of those types *inside* another monad transformer) match that constraint! That's the entire point - you literally just instantiate the value at different types to get the different orderings (and different orderings give different semantics for some transformers!). The "inheriting" you describe is exactly the mechanism of `mtl` - I would recommend the [paper linked in the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl).

Comment: @leftaroundabout ok will try read that :) The compiler requires `-XFlexibleContexts`, so that must be some sneaky hack, right?

Comment: @IlyaSmagin: there's not much hacky about `FlexibleContexts`, it's one of the extensions you can turn on with little concern; it basically just disables some restrictions of standard Haskell which make it easier to write a compiler; but GHC doesn't need this. When it requests `Overlappable` or even `IncoherentInstances`, that's when you should get wary...

Answer (score 3):

You can *lift* a `Writer w a` into a [**`MonadWriter`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html#t:MonadWriter) instance by, something like:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer (MonadWriter, Writer, runWriter, tell)

lift' :: MonadWriter w m => Writer w a -> m a
lift' wr = do
    let (a, w) = runWriter wr
    tell w    -- manually re-log the log msg
    return a  -- wrap value into new context
```

then, you may simply write:

```
gameRoutine :: WriterT [String] (ReaderT Env (State Viable)) NUM
gameRoutine = do
    a <- lift' writerFunction
```

as long as `writerFunction :: Writer [String] a` can be specialized with `a ~ NUM`.